# How to validate type family after storing it in json?

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-families

The following code won't compile and gives the error of

> Couldn't match type ‘c1’ with ‘c’
>         ‘c1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>           a pattern with constructor:
>             SomeReq :: forall c. Conn c => Req c -> SomeReq,
>           in an equation for ‘run’

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

module Main where

import qualified Data.Text as T

class Conn c where
  data Auth c :: *
  data Env c :: *
  data Req c :: *

  getEnv :: Auth c -> IO (Env c)
  runReq :: Env c -> Req c -> IO String

data SomeAuth = forall c. (Conn c) => SomeAuth (Auth c)
data SomeReq = forall c. (Conn c) => SomeReq (Auth c)

run :: SomeAuth -> SomeReq -> IO String
run (SomeAuth auth) (SomeReq req) = do
  env <- getEnv auth
  runReq env req

main :: IO ()
main = return ()
```

The reason for the existentials is that I need to store these data types in json. `(Auth c)` and `(Req c)` are always stored seperatly, but are always used together.

I'm assuming that the only possible way to make this work is to have some kind of runtime check to validate that these types match up. I'm not sure how to do that though.

Comment: Are you saying that your JSON storage determines what `c` is? Or is `c` determined by the static structure of the code?

Comment: `c` is a service on which we can run the request. For example S3, or Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a `SomeAuth` and a `SomeReq`, you have no way to find out whether the types they wrap are the same. If there are finitely many possibilities (a finite "universe"), then you can use a GADT to tag them:

```
data CTag c where
  C1T :: CTag C1
  C2T :: CTag C2
  ...
```

sticking a `CTag` in `SomeAuth` and one in `SomeReq` and pattern matching.

If `c` could be any old thing, your best bet is to use `Data.Typeable`, adding a `Typeable` constraint to the `SomeAuth` and `SomeReq` constructors. Once you open them both, you'll be able to find out if the types match, and if so get evidence of it.

Comment: Thanks for that simple solution. Is it possible to have a generic function that constructs SomeAuth? Something like `mkSomeAuth :: Auth c -> SomeAuth`

Comment: To be more specific I am going with adding CTags in SomeAuth, so I guess the question is how to go from `(Auth c) -> CTag c`

Comment: I went back to play around with adding `Typable` as a constraint and I'm a bit lost. Could you point to an example?

Comment: @whitehead, if I get a chance. Things are a bit crazy right now.